# Using Group By in a SqlDataSource with a stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures

I have a `SqlDataSource` I would like to use with a DropDownList. The only issue is that the stored procedure doesn't group the data. So I am seeing multiple values where I would like to group by them.

Is there a way to group data from a stored procedure in the `SqlDataSource`?

Example datasource:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="JobApprovalEditDS" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:JobClose %>" SelectCommand="up_JobApprovalsSelect" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="ShowAll" DefaultValue="1" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="AllPhases" DefaultValue="1" />
        </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: No, it will display whatever is returned by the SP you would have to change the SP to return grouped data or if you cannot then do the grouping and binding in code and stop using the `SqlDataSource` control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to alter the stored procedure to group the results. If not you will need to send them to a custom class that handles the grouping then send the grouped results to the control but this is an unnecessary and costly step.